# Google Drive excessive battery drain

Tags: macos, battery, monterey, google-apps

I noticed that my battery is draining faster than expected and after looking at the Activity Monitor -> Energy, I noticed that Google Drive has the highest value in the 12 hrs Power column. Is there any settings that can be changed besides pausing the syncing?

I'm running an Apple M1 Max on macOS 12.1 (21C52).

Comment: Does macOS 12.2 change the behaviour?